# Diodes in parallel - where does the surplus current go?

Tags: voltage, led, current, diodes

I'm trying to stabilize current through a LED, and have run into this theoretical problem. This is the circuit:

[image]

Notes - The resistors were chosen such that there is a current difference between the LED branch and the outgoing branch.

The question is, what would happen in this circuit? Would I1 start at 2A? Would I2 start at 1A? Where does the extra current (I1-I2) go? Does it go into the top branch? What about the diodes there?

Would something burn? If so what is the dynamic behavor?

I'm in way above my head here :)

Thanks!

Comment: KCL dictates there is no extra current. It all sums up.

Comment: stabilizing current through one diode by putting four diodes in parallel with it would be something I'd consider a bit of a gamble.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am trying to understand the theory here, not going to gamble :)

Comment: @winny so where does the 1amp from the LED branch (which doesn't continue on to I2) go?

Comment: I'm not sure which theory you're trying to understand, that's my problem! Your circuit is labeled with wrong assumptions, namely that the forward voltages are stable, and that the currents are independent of the voltage across your 3.2 Ω resistor. That makes no sense. As winny said, current needs to add up – so your I2 needs to be I1 + (current through your four diodes in the top branch).

Comment: @MarcusMüller are the voltage drops over the diodes in the diode branch not 0.7V each? Is that what is going to "break"?

Comment: @AviadP. that is one problem, yes, the other is that you're literally forgetting the first lecture on the first day of electrical engineering: that the sum of currents flowing into a node needs to be zero. That's the worse problem. This is so basic that answering this would best be done with "please revisit a basic introduction to electrical networks", as your question now spans from these ultra-basics to exponential current-voltage curves of diodes to temperature-dependent behaviour. That's really too much for one question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller so you're saying there would be current going backwards through the diodes at the top branch? sorry or that the voltage drop there would be lower such that I2 can be higher

Comment: @AviadP. no. You will have to revisit your very basic material on electrical networks. I'm voting to close this as too broad, sorry.

Comment: @MarcusMüller no offense, but I don't see how basic introduction to electrical networks can solve this question...

Comment: Notice what I'm asking here, I'm asking whether I1 would start at 2A and would I2 start at 1A I am not asserting that the sum of the currents is not 0 at any one junction

Comment: @AviadP. no offense, but I don't see how someone forgetting about KCL would *understand* any answer. So, go back to basics :) and yes, you are asserting that; otherwise, you ẃouldn't be assuming wrong things about I2.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but I do understand KCL - I'm asking what would be the dynamic behavior? what would be the currents measured (over time) in I1 and in I2 and would something burn, and if so what?

Comment: No current will flow through 4 Si diodes because voltage across them is 2.66V only. 4Si diodes needs 2.8V to open.

Comment: @AviadP. Then you don't understand Ohm's law? you're really making conflicting assumptions and statements here. Your claim that the node between the two branches and the resistor is at 3.2 V is plain wrong.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický one might argue that this is also an oversimplification.

Comment: @MarcusMüller isn't it true that the voltage drop on a diode is ~0.7V? maybe that's what I don't undertstand.

Comment: yes, that is not true. connect your diode to a 0.3 V source. Now, can the voltage drop be 0.7V ? Connect it to a 1V source. Can the voltage drop be 0.7 V?

Comment: and I mean, you *already know* that constant forward voltage for diodes doesn't exist – or how else did you calculate the series resistor to your LED?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I calculated it such that in theory (under my wrong assumptions about voltage drops) it would follow that I1 would have to be 2A

Comment: so, now think about what happens if you made that series resistor 80% the ohms. It might help looking at an actual LED datasheet.

Comment: You can't just stick some (seemingly) arbitrary numbers onto a diagram and then ask why it doesn't make sense. You seems to have made some (unfounded) assumptions about what currents will flow in particular branches of your circuit, and that's the root of your confusion. *Calculate* those currents based on what's really going on in your circuit and you'll see that it does all add up as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to start with the assumed forward-voltage drop of the diodes (which you have done), and then verify if they satisfy the KCL/KVL laws.

In this case, you found out that by assuming V1 = 3.5V and V2 = 3.2V, the corresponding currents would be I1 = 2A and I3 = 1A and looking for the exit of the "extra" current (I2 = I1 - I3). By KCL law, this *should* go out towards I2 into the 4 diodes which is impossible since you cannot pass a reverse current into the diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB2pRs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the conclusion here must be, one of your assumed voltages is incorrect since the KVL/KCL equations will not hold up. So you narrow it further by only assuming 1 of the two diode voltages as correct (i.e. only one diode path is forward-biased): V1 = 3.5V or V2 = 3.2V. Then solve the KCL equations again.

If you try to solve the KCL equations assuming the LED forward path only (V1 = 3.5), you will find out that:

V1 = 3.5V is correct
V2 = 3.5 * (3.2/3.35) = 3.343V
I1 = I3 = 1.045 A
I2 = 0 (not enough voltage drop for 4-diodes)

The 4-diode path cannot conduct current because V2 = 3.343V is greater than the required (6-2.8)V voltage drop for the 4-diodes to turn on.

Comment: _"The 4-diode path cannot conduct current because V2 = 3.343V is greater than the required (6-2.8)V voltage drop for the 4-diodes to turn on."_ Marcus Müller's [simulation](https://tinyurl.com/2h5fcvbf) (in the comments) suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Velvel Ahh, I checked the simulation and his simulation is based on the realistic parameters of the diode. So the voltage drop for the diode actually varies (lesser) to allow lesser current flow below the actual forward-bias voltage. Mine was the approximated version of the forward current behavior where it only "turns on" when the forward voltage drop is specifically met. This is the usual analysis when you do it by hand without any simulators.

Comment: I may need to add this as an addendum later when I have time.

Comment: Would be nice if you'd add that caveat.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvLYry.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the four diodes are treated as a 2.8 volt battery, then all the voltages and currents in the OP are correct. The "extra current" will return to the battery. The current direction would be from right to left in the upper branch.

But diodes aren't batteries. The 0.7 volts across each of them is due to current directed from left to right in the diode branch. And so it must be that:$$I_3>0$$ in the direction shown.
Then by Kirchhoff's current law:$$I_2=I_1+I_3$$ implying that \$I_2\$ is greater than both \$I_1\$ and \$I_3\$ separately.

**So \$I_2\$ cannot be 1A.** It must be  \$I_3+2\text{A}\$

So what value is \$I_3\$? It can be any **arbitrary** value greater than zero. Of course the on-off-0.7V approximation to a real diode is being used.

Let's pick \$I_3=1.2\text{A}\$ then \$I_2=3.2\text{A}\$, And so $$R_2=1.0\Omega$$

For a more realistic treatment refer to the [data sheet for the diod](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf)e (say a 1N4001) as shown below:

Now the diode current is no longer arbitrary. We cannot pick a value that we like. For a 0.7V drop the diode current must be 30mA. $$I_2=2.03\text{A}$$ implying that $$R_2=1.6\Omega$$

Three things deflected the analysis

1. Unknowingly treating the diode string as a voltage source.
2. Forgetting to include \$I_3\$ in the calculation of \$I_2\$.
3. Using a simplifying approximation that forced the diode current to be undefined. An arbitray choice was required.

[image]